# Open a new window with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I want to open a new window using the openWindow() method that I can see in the [rdoc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/Client/GeneratedDriver.html#open_window-instance_method), but whenever I attempt to run my code, I am told that the method does not exist.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
$browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox #I've tried chrome too to the same effect
$browser.navigate.to("http://google.com")
$browser.openWindow("http://cnet.com","ASDF") #This doesn't work.
$browser.open_window("http://cnet.com","ASDF") #This doesn't work either.
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could set the record straight on how to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed in [this article](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/4-work-with-multiple-windows), the correct way to use the API is:

```
  @driver.get 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows'
  main_window = @driver.window_handle
  @driver.find_element(css: '.example a').click
  windows = @driver.window_handles
  windows.each do |window|
    if main_window != window
      @new_window = window
    end
  end
  @driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
  @driver.title.should_not =~ /New Window/
  @driver.switch_to.window(@new_window)
  @driver.title.should =~ /New Window/
```

Which will have the following behavior:

- Load the page
- Get the window handle for the current window
- Take an action that opens a new window
- Get the window handle for the new window
- Switch between the windows as needed

Comment: As a side note, for my intended application, I did not end up using this feature as I wanted to do a lot more with the windows than was supported.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you could use
    openWindow method but

To open a new window you will have to open a new instance of your firefox browser again

so ,try doing something like

```
$browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox 
$browser.navigate.to("http://google.com")

$browser_new = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox 
$browser_new.goto("http://cnet.com")
```

Comment: I had considered that, but that also means that I then have to create a method for managing my various browser instances, which seemed a little bit like overkill. However, if no one else proposes a solution within a week, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Turns out that making a method for managing browser instances is totally necessary. Selenium does not keep track of these things on it's own, nor should it, as this is quite outside the scope of it's use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Selenium, but according to your own question the name of the method is [`open_window`](http://Selenium.GoogleCode.Com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/Client/GeneratedDriver.html#open_window-instance_method) not `openWindow`.

Comment: I have corrected it, but unfortunately can't seem to find the rdoc so that I could link to what I'm referencing.

Comment: [This doc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/Client/GeneratedDriver.html#open_window-instance_method) seems to imply that the method is actually open_window(). Regardless, I have tried both to no avail.